# What is StringCbprintf and how's this different than general sprintf?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, printf

I am going through a previously written code and I found `StringCbPrintf()` function

I found declaration on `msdn` site like this :

```
HRESULT StringCbPrintf(
  _Out_  LPTSTR pszDest,
  _In_   size_t cbDest,
  _In_   LPCTSTR pszFormat,
  _In_    ...
);
```

What is `_in_` and `_out_` here ?

And why is it needed when we already have `sprintf()` ?

Comment: Added "windows" and "winapi" tags, since this question involves SAL annotations, which are Windows specific.

Comment: Note that `_in_` and `_out_` are not valid SAL (they are `_In_` and `_Out_`, with initial capital letter). An alternative valid SAL is with leading double underscores (and lowercase initial letter): `__in` and `__out`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_In_` and `_Out_` (**note**: neither `_in_/_out`_ as you wrote, nor `__In__/__Out__` with double underscores, as written in some other answer) are so called **SAL Annotations**. They can be used with `/analyze` compiler option, and can help identify bugs and problems like buffer overruns etc. with raw C buffers and pointers. In addition to [MSDN documentation on SAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you can read also this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2006/05/19/602077.aspx).

Someone ironically (and *wrongly*) wrote that:

> "In the rest of the world, inputs are const pointers but I guess that
>   was too simple. :)"

missing the fact that SAL is *more powerful* than that. In fact, with SAL you can also specify the maximum size of a destination buffer, indicating which parameter contains the destination buffer size; e.g. if you open `<strsafe.h>` header, you can read that the actual SAL annotations used for `StringCbPrintfW` (the Unicode version of `StringCbPrintf`) is something like that:

```
STRSAFEAPI
StringCbPrintfW(
    __out_bcount(cbDest) STRSAFE_LPWSTR pszDest,
    __in size_t cbDest,
    __in __format_string STRSAFE_LPCWSTR pszFormat,
    ...)
{
    ....
```

Note how the `__out_bcount(cbDest)` SAL annotation applied to the `pszDest` parameter specifies that this is a pointer to an *output* buffer (`__out`), which *size* is expressed *in bytes* (`_bcount`) by the parameter `cbDest`. As you can see, this is a **rich** annotation (richer than simple "`const`" or "non `const`").

In my opinion, SAL is kind of useless if you write C++ code with robust container classes like `std::vector` or `std::string`, which know their own size, etc. But SAL can be useful in C-ish code with raw pointers (like several Win32 APIs).

About the second part of your question:

> "Why we need `StringCbPrintf` if we already have `sprintf`"

the main reason is that `sprintf` is an **unsafe** and buffer overruns-prone function; instead with `StringCbPrintf` you must specify the maximum size of the destination buffer, and this can help preventing buffer overruns (which are security enemies).

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tries to explain that for you:

> Compared to the functions it replaces, StringCbPrintf provides additional processing for 
>   proper buffer handling in your code. Poor buffer handling is implicated in many security issues that involve buffer overruns. StringCbPrintf always null-terminates a nonzero-length destination buffer.

The `__In__` and `__Out__` decorators are used in Microsoft API:s to denote how a pointer argument is used. In the rest of the world, inputs are `const` pointers but I guess that was too simple. :)

Comment: Nice ..It means `__in__` means `const` and `__out__` for output buffers . But why is it needed ? we have sprintf right ?

Comment: +1 anyway for __in__ and __out__ , I was thinking a kind of binding param like we have in database functions

Comment: Note that `__In__` and `__Out__` are wrong: valid SAL's are `__in/__out` (as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402(v=vs.80).aspx)) or `_In_/_Out_` (as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402(v=vs.100).aspx)). Moreover, -1 because SAL is _richer_ than simple `const` correctness.

Comment: Note that LPCTSTR pszFormat, already contains a const (long pointer to constant tchar string).

Answer (score 2):

As it is said [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms647510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> StringCbPrintf is a replacement for the following functions:
>
> - sprintf, swprintf, _stprintf
> - wsprintf
> - wnsprintf
> - _snprintf, _snwprintf, _sntprintf

So it doesn't only replace `sprintf`, but also those to work with `wchar`, for example. It also introduces additional buffer processing to prevent buffer overruns (as stated in the same msdn article). It also *always* null-terminates the destination buffer. `_in_` and `_out_` are there to show you which parameters are input ones, and which are output ones. Those are most likely `#define`d as nothing, and go away before the compilation begins.

Comment: good this line was written in msdn but the problem was with __in__ and __out__ .. anyway +1

Comment: @Omkant, in many books you might read on C++, the authors actually recommend to distinguish input and output function arguments. One solution is using such macros, e.g. `#define IN` and `#define OUT`. They clearly show the argument type, and go away before the compilation begins. I'm not encouraging you to do it, that's just some additional information :P